# Explicar el funcionamiento de transaction.atomic()

Tags: python, django

Estoy empezando un proyecto en django y mirando ejemplos veo que usan transaction.atomic() para guardar en la base de datos pero no comprendo exactamente el funcionamiento.

Comment: Cuando usas un bloque atómico, lo que quieres decirle al programa y a la base de datos es que cualquier cosa que se ejecute dentro de ese bloque o función debe hacerse si o si, es decir todo depende de todo. Un ejemplo es que puedes hacer un `save` a un modelo, y luego hacer un `save` a otro, pero el segundo falla, más el primero si se guardó, y hay casos donde el primero necesita si o si que el segundo se guarde, para esos casos existen las transacciones atómicas. Si hay un fallo dentro del bloque es como si hicieras un rollback

Comment: lo que quieres decir es que si tengo un en un bloque transaction.atomic() dos modelos y el primero se guarda sin problema pero el segundo da algun error , los datos del primero se eliminan y todo empieza de nuevo?? o se mantinen los del primero

Comment: Exacto, los datos del primero no se guardan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intentaré explicarlo con un ejemplo.

Imagina que tienes una clase cuenta donde vamos a almacenar un importe. Algo así:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Cuenta(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
    )
    importe_total = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
    )
```

Ahora queremos tanto sacar dinero como guardarlo:

```
def guardar_dinero(self, cantidad):
    self.importe_total += cantidad
    self.save()

def sacar_dinero(self, cantidad):
    if cantidad > self.balance:
        raise errors.InsufficientFunds()
    self.importe_total -= cantidad
    self.save()
```

Son dos ejemplos muy sencillos que si estamos trabajando con una gran cantidad de operaciones que podrían darse a la vez tanto la opción de sacar como de guardar pues tendríamos un gran problema. Lo explico:

- Usuario A y B comparten una cuenta con un importe de 100€. **A la vez** realizan una operación diferente cada uno.
- Usuario B saca 30€  => actualizamos el importe => 100€  -  30$ = 70€.
- Usuario A guarda 50€ => actualizamos el importe => 100€ + 50€ = 0150€.

Si te fijas el saldo final en la cuenta es de 150€ cuando debería ser de 120€.

¿Por qué pasa esto? Pues porque cuando realizan la operación el importe en la cuenta es de 100€ para los dos, su operación la hacen sobre este importe, por lo tanto, al final tendrá un saldo extra de 30€.

Con atomic **bloquea** la segunda operación (guardar) hasta que la primera no termina (sacar) así la segunda operación contará con el valor de 70€ en lugar de 100€. Te recomiendo leer la **"Pessimistic approach"** del artículo de medium que te menciono más abajo para que tengas una ejemplo completo de como usarlo, no lo expongo aquí puesto que solamente preguntas por qué es atomic no por como usarlo.

Si no vas a tener un volumen de consultas grande o no vas a usar datos delicados, como podría ser el dinero, no te recomendaría usarlo porque ralentiza mucho las operaciones.

Te dejo un enlace a la [documentación oficial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) así como el [artículo de medium que consulté](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2) para obtener esta información y que te recomiendo.

Además **cuidado con las tablas relacionadas**, si quieres interactuar con un campo que tenga una relación (ForeignKey, etc.) cuidado porque atomic bloquea las dos tablas haciendo que la tabla relacional tampoco se pueda usar. En la documentación de Django tienes un ejemplo con un `select_for_update()` debería funcionar.

También te dejo un [ejemplo completo](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/bullet-proofing-django-models-c080739be4e) de como manejar una cuenta bancaria.